# How to add variables

Tags: python

Im making a odds even code i'm struggling to add variables

Im pretty new to coding

```
from random import *
print("This is the game odds, evens")
game = input("Do you choose odds or evens?")
number = input("What number do you choose")
MyNumber = randint(1,10)
num = game + MyNumber
if num % 2 == 0:
  print("even")
if num % 2 == 1:
  print("odd")
```

I got

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in 
    num = game + MyNumber
TypeError: must be str, not int"

I don't know how to fix it

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `num = game + MyNumber`? If `game` is something like "odds", and `MyNumber` is something like 7, what do you expect `"odds" + 7` to do?

Comment: The objective of the game is not clear. Can you please explain what are you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: game is either odd or even, say odd. MyNumber is an integer, say 3. What are you trying to do by `num = game + MyNumber`? What do you expect `odd + 3` to be? I think you are trying to do: `num = number + MyNumber`. Still not good, you must do `num = int(number) + MyNumber`.

Comment: @FatihAkici yeah you're right than you so much

Answer (score 0):

use `int(game)` instead of just `game` to convert it to numeric

Comment: Even in that cae, `int('odds')` or `int('evens') ` will only throw a `ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for your game:

```
from random import randint

game = input("Odds (1) or evens (2). Please choose 1 or 2.")
my_random = randint(1,10)
print "My random: {}".format(my_random)

if (my_random % 2 == 0 and game == 2) or (my_random % 2 != 0 and game == 1):
    print True
else:
    print False
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` method by default gets the input as `str` so we need to convert it to `int`. Just make this change to your code and you should be fine.

```
game = int(input("Do you choose odds or evens?"))
number = int(input("What number do you choose"))
```

Good Luck!!

Answer (score -1):

I understand where you may have been confused. Theoretically if the user enters 6 and the random number is 3 you would expect to get 9 and the code shouldn't break.  However, an input will return a string.  So the program now thinks you are trying to add 3 + '6'.

To fix this, you can cast the result of the input to int(game) int(number)

Comment: What is `int(odd)`?